# Can't center a container from small to large screens

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwindcss to style my website that I'm currently building with React the problem I'm facing right now is that i cant center a `div` element in these screens which are `sm, md, lg`
the same method worked in previous sections i built but it is not working in this one
the code is as follow

```
const ContactForm = () => {
  return (
    <section id="contactForm">
      <div className="container max-w-6xl mx-auto my-8 py-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-md ">
        <h2 className="text-3xl font-semibold font-poppins "> Ready To Talk? </h2>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default ContactForm
```

Comment: You're using `mx-auto` to center elements?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Yeah i'm using it to center the the div container it works fine in xl screen but not the ones mentioned above

Comment: What about using Flexbox, `flex justify-content-center align-items-center`?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour do you mean `justify-center align-center`  ?cause i've never seen what you aforementioned

Comment: Oops, yeah, true. I meant `flex justify-center content-center` should center elements correctly.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour those latter you mentioned are used to center contents that's inside the container but not the container itself

Comment: Yes, isn't that what you wanted? You want to center the `<div>` itself? `flex self-center justify-self-center`?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour I'm sorry it didn't work either

Answer (score 2):

I some how managed to solve the problem the trick is to add padding on right and left side `px-{size}` in the section tag it works fine and dandy

```
const ContactForm = () => {
  return (
    <section id="contactForm" className="px-7">
      <div className="container mx-auto max-w-[1130px] my-9 py-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-md">
        <h2 className="text-3xl font-semibold font-poppins w-1/3"> Ready To Talk? </h2>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default ContactForm
```